# Cannot understand why one extra character is being received from input file

Tags: c

I have this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {

    FILE * stream = fopen("abc1", "r");            
    int c, i; 
    i=1;
    do 
    {
        c = fgetc(stream);
        if (c == EOF)
            printf("c is EOF\n");
        printf("in loop : %d %c\n", i, c);        
        i++;

    } while(isspace(c)); 
    printf("%d\n", i);           
}
```

File `abc1` contains 4 spaces only.
I was hoping to see the o/p `c is EOF` printed before `in loop : 5` but it is appearing after that. Why so ?

Output:

```
$ ./ungetctest 
in loop : 1  
in loop : 2  
in loop : 3  
in loop : 4  
in loop : 5 

c is EOF
in loop : 6 �
7
```

Answer (score 4):

The blank line after `in loop : 5` indicates that the 5th character is a newline. Your file must contain four spaces and a newline.

You could confirm this by changing `%c` to `%d`, then you would get the ASCII code of the character, `32` for space and `10` for newline.

The `isspace` function is also true for newlines.

If you're fairly sure it doesn't contain one, then try opening in `"rb"` mode. In `"r"` mode (aka. read text mode) the operating system may perform line ending translations, and possibly attach a newline to the last line of the file if the file it didn't contain one.

Comment: Another good suggestion would be to open the input file with a hex editor.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `isspace()` function to check the condition true or not. After 4 spaces you are having `\n` in your file, so this `\n` also evaluated as true in `isspace()` function. The Standard white-space characters are:

```
' '     (0x20)  space (SPC)
'\t'    (0x09)  horizontal tab (TAB)
'\n'    (0x0a)  newline (LF) 
'\v'    (0x0b)  vertical tab (VT)
'\f'    (0x0c)  feed (FF)
'\r'    (0x0d)  carriage return (CR)
```

When `EOF` occurs `while(isspace(c));` conditions fails. But you are using `do----while()` loop, so every time it executes once before checking the condition. When `c` contains `EOF` you will get the following output-

```
c is EOF
in loop : 6 � // This is due to printf("in loop : %d %c\n", i, c);
```

In that printf It is trying to print `EOF` in Character format. So you are getting the some Unknown symbol.

So in this type of situations when `EOF` occurs Stop/`return` the execution of the program.
Try the following change-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {

    int c, i;
    FILE * stream = fopen("abc1", "r");         
    if(stream == NULL){
            printf("Failed to open the file\n");
            return 0;
    }
    i=1;
    do
    {
            c = fgetc(stream);
            if (c == EOF){
                    printf("c is EOF\n");
                    return 0;
            }
            printf("in loop : %d %c\n", i, c); 
            i++;

    } while(isspace(c));
    printf("%d\n", i);        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From your output it looks like you have a newline character after your spaces.
After having run your code on my computer with a valid file here is the output I get:

```
in loop : 1  
in loop : 2  
in loop : 3  
in loop : 4  
c is EOF
in loop : 5 \377
6
```